# How do I display, pan and center google map after I have collected a search item from mysql database?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have collected all data from MySQL DB and displayed it on google map using markers. I also added a search function to do a name or address search to get a specific customer from DB. The search feature is functioning but I am unable to then use the searched data to pan, zoom and center the map to the customer. What am I missing in order to be able to do this?

Here is my js file code:

```js
    var map;
    var geocoder;
    
    //Code to load the map with center point of Monterey MA
    function initMap() {
        var monterey = {lat: 42.181613, lng: -73.215013};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: monterey,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            labels: true,
        });
    
        //collect customer data and geocoder object - declare geocoder as global
        var cusdata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
        codeAddress(cusdata);
    
        var allData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('allData').innerHTML);
        showAllCustomers(allData)
    
        var searchData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('searchData').innerHTML);
        showSearchedCustomer(searchData)
        
    }
    
    function showAllCustomers(allData) {
        //declare info window variable outside of loop to allow to clear when selecting other markers
        var infoWind = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(allData, function(data){
            var content = document.createElement('div');
            var strong = document.createElement('strong');
            
            strong.textContent = [data.name + ' ' + data.address];
            content.appendChild(strong);
    
            //add image to infowindow - you are also able to add image path to mysql and then append dynamically
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = 'images/santahat.png';
            img.style.width = '50px';
            content.appendChild(img);
    
            //Create markers for customer locations and customize
            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
              map: map,
              icon: iconBase + 'homegardenbusiness.png'
            });
    
            // Add event listener to open info window and show customer name
            marker.addListener('mouseover', function(){
                infoWind.setContent(content);
                infoWind.open(map, marker);
            
            //add event listener to zoom in to clicked customer
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                    map.setZoom(20);
                    });  
            
            });
        }) 
    }
    
    //google maps geocoding code for address to collect lat lng from customer addresses
    function codeAddress(cusdata) {
       Array.prototype.forEach.call(cusdata, function(data){
            var address = data.name + ' ' + data.address;
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == 'OK') {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    
    //create object that collects the lat and lng data and pass function to update customers lat lng
                var points = {};
                points.id = data.id;
                points.lat = map.getCenter().lat();
                points.lng = map.getCenter().lng();
                updateCustomersWithLatLng(points);
              } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
              }
            });
        });
    }
    
    //create update customers function that updates db using ajax call
    function updateCustomersWithLatLng(points) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"post",
            data: points,
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res)
            }
        })
        
    }
    
    
    
    //When search customers is clicked create function to zoom in to the searched customer
    function showSearchedCustomer(searchData) {
    
        // var searchedCus = { ? };
        // map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        //  zoom: 20,
        //  center: searchedCus,
        //   });
    
        //declare info window vairable outside of loop to allow to clear if selecting other markers
        var infoWind = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(searchData, function(data){
            var content = document.createElement('div');
            var strong = document.createElement('strong');
            
            strong.textContent = [data.name + ' ' + data.address];
            content.appendChild(strong);
    
            //add image to infowindow - you are also able to add image path to mysql and then append dynamically
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = 'images/santahat.png';
            img.style.width = '50px';
            content.appendChild(img);
    
            //Create marker for searched customer location and customize
            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
              map: map,
              icon: iconBase + 'homegardenbusiness.png'
            });
    
            // Add event listner to open info window and show customer name
            marker.addListener('mouseover', function(){
                infoWind.setContent(content);
                infoWind.open(map, marker);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: How/where are you trying to center the map on the customer?  How do you want to set the zoom level?  It would be better if you could provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, preferably a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in your question.

Comment: Here is the repository link to folder https://github.com/bodenmethod/googleMaps

Comment: Upon map loading on page it pulls ALL customers from the database and puts the markers on the map.

Comment: I then added a search box, allowing you to search for a specific customer. Upon clicking the submit/search button the data is pulled from the MYSQL DB - this is the point where I don't know how to use those pulled lat and lng data from that searched customer to then zoom in to (zoom: 20). I can print the searched customer data to the page but not use that data to zoom into that customer. Thank you.